# Xiaomi Redmi5 Cannot Connect to Phaser 3020 Printer

Tags: networking, wi-fi

I am trying to connect Xiaomi Redmi5 with a Phaser 3020 via Wi-Fi Direct. My iOS devices connect just fine.  Xerox Printer Services cannot discover the printer. Tried it with the IP of the printer. Did not help. With the Default Printer Service (in Xiaomi called "System printing services" ->Find Wi-Fi Direct printers I *reach* the point whereby the printer is found judging by the message "add DIRECT-Nv Phaser 3020". Tapping on it invokes a message Connecting to DIRECT-Nv Phaser 3020 and the printer seems to start crunching for a sec. After that a message appears saying **You may need to approve this connection on your printer's front panel**, but the printer has no panel except of 2 buttons (powerOff and WPS button) .Then followed by "Could not connect to DIRECT-Nv Phaser 3020". Apparently, the approval by the printer failed but I have no clue how to grant that approval. Tried pressing the two buttons in various combinations to no avail. Is there a way to connect this printer with the Redmi5 or they are intrinsically incompatible?

Comment: @beeshyams In the instructions is only mentioned, how to enable wi-fi direct (which already is enabled). But no mentioned about wifi icon on the printer (which i see none). So how could blinking wifi icon appear, when there is no such icon on the printer?

Comment: @beeshyams all the setup you sent I have already done (enabled direct wifi, even used it with connection with my laptop) - as mentioned in my post *I HAVE SUCCESSFULLY* print via wifi but only on LAPTOT. I could not connect to android phone. On the printer, there are only 2 buttons (again, read the post). Once I am trying to connect with the **phone**, then it requires approval of the connection on the **printer panel**, but there is not printer *panel*. So how can I approve connection then? You do not have to send me any documentation, since I have read it all.

Comment: PS: the android is trying to connect via `System printing sevices`. These services requires the approval of the printer. The wifi-direct by itself is secured by password, which I entered when connecting to the wifi (with password provided by the printer manufacturer - known from the printer configuration list), so the wifi was established, but the then even with the secured wifi, the connection by itself seems to require approval by the printer (which I do not understand why).

Comment: but worse - as mentioned many times above - I have no way to approve the connection **on** the printer, when the printer has no panel

Comment: PS, the reason why I connected with laptop (using windows), is because I used installation exe -> https://www.support.xerox.com/en-us/product/phaser-3020/content/129484. After installation I had IP of the printer on local network (IP something lik 1.0.0.32), so even the phone could see - but again, cannot connect

Comment: *Intrinsically incompatible with Android phones*, see [question in Xerox forums](https://forum.support.xerox.com/t5/Printing/Samsung-Galaxy-Note8-Cannot-Connect-to-Phaser-3020-Printer/td-p/227441),  Amazon reviews [search for print](https://www.amazon.in/Xerox-3020_BI-Function-Wireless-Printer/product-reviews/B00QMIUJFU/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_prev_1?ref_=d6k_applink_bb_dls_failed&pageNumber=1&filterByKeyword=Print), [print plug in app does not support 3020, see app description](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xerox.printservice)

Comment: [Mopria plugin works](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mopria.printplugin) for some Xerox devices. You can try or ask the last post owner which is the third party [plug in that works](https://forum.support.xerox.com/t5/Printing/Cannot-print-from-Android-phone/m-p/236420) // Another alternative is [Google cloud print](https://forum.support.xerox.com/t5/Printing/Cannot-print-from-Android-phone/m-p/236420) which doesn't work reliably as reported in forums// This [you tube video](https://youtu.be/sajL1zxuKgo) also recommended Mopria